# getting running job id from BigQueryOperator using xcom

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I want to get Bigquery's job id from BigQueryOperator.

I saw in bigquery_operator.py file the following line:

```
context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='job_id', value=job_id)
```

I don't know if this is airflow's job id or BigQuery job id, if it's BigQuery job id how can I get it using xcom from downstream task?.

I tried to do the following in downstream Pythonoperator:

```
def write_statistics(**kwargs):
  job_id = kwargs['templates_dict']['job_id']
  print('tamir')
  print(kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='create_tmp_big_query_table',key='job_id'))
  print(kwargs['ti'])
  print(job_id)

t3 = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='create_tmp_big_query_table',
        bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
        destination_dataset_table= DATASET_TABLE_NAME,
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        sql = """
        #standardSQL...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI is great for checking whether an XCom was written to or not, which I'd recommend you do even before you try to reference it in a separate task so you don't need to worry about whether you're fetching it correctly or not. Click your `create_tmp_big_query_table` task -> Task Instance Details -> XCom. It'll look something like the following:

[image: xcom page]

In your case, the code looks right to me, but I'm guessing your version of Airflow doesn't have the change that added saving job id into an XCom. This feature was added in https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5195, which is currently only on `master` and currently not part of the most recent stable release (1.10.3). See for yourself in the 1.10.3 version of the [BigQueryOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py#L210).

Your options are to wait for it to be in a release (...sometimes takes awhile), running off a version of `master` with that change, or temporarily copy over the newer version of the operator as a custom operator. In the last case, I'd suggest naming it something like `BigQueryOperatorWithXcom` with a note to replace it with the built-in operator once it's released.

Answer (score 0):

The JOB ID within bigquery_operator.py is the BQ JOB ID. You can understand it looking at the previous lines:

```
 if isinstance(self.sql, str):
            job_id = self.bq_cursor.run_query(
                sql=self.sql,
                destination_dataset_table=self.destination_dataset_table,
                write_disposition=self.write_disposition,
                allow_large_results=self.allow_large_results,
                flatten_results=self.flatten_results,
                udf_config=self.udf_config,
                maximum_billing_tier=self.maximum_billing_tier,
                maximum_bytes_billed=self.maximum_bytes_billed,
                create_disposition=self.create_disposition,
                query_params=self.query_params,
                labels=self.labels,
                schema_update_options=self.schema_update_options,
                priority=self.priority,
                time_partitioning=self.time_partitioning,
                api_resource_configs=self.api_resource_configs,
                cluster_fields=self.cluster_fields,
                encryption_configuration=self.encryption_configuration
            )
        elif isinstance(self.sql, Iterable):
            job_id = [
                self.bq_cursor.run_query(
                    sql=s,
                    destination_dataset_table=self.destination_dataset_table,
                    write_disposition=self.write_disposition,
                    allow_large_results=self.allow_large_results,
                    flatten_results=self.flatten_results,
                    udf_config=self.udf_config,
                    maximum_billing_tier=self.maximum_billing_tier,
                    maximum_bytes_billed=self.maximum_bytes_billed,
                    create_disposition=self.create_disposition,
                    query_params=self.query_params,
                    labels=self.labels,
                    schema_update_options=self.schema_update_options,
                    priority=self.priority,
                    time_partitioning=self.time_partitioning,
                    api_resource_configs=self.api_resource_configs,
                    cluster_fields=self.cluster_fields,
                    encryption_configuration=self.encryption_configuration
                )
                for s in self.sql]
```

Eventually, run_with_configuration method returns self.running_job_id from BQ